# Js external file not work but on page it works. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, external

I created a right menu open code where when I add js code in external file it not work and when I add is on that page it is works.

Yes, there is many post in stackoverflow which have same issue but I try to do that all solution is there. Then , after I creating thus post.

Even I added `wimdow load, Document load` and all function but it not works.

Below is my js code, how I make it as when I add in js file it will works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//$(function() {
  var doubleClicked = false;
  $(document).on("contextmenu", function (e) {
   if(doubleClicked == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height()/2;
    var windowWidth = $(window).width()/2;
    if(e.clientY > windowHeight && e.clientX <= windowWidth) {
      $("#arltcntn").css("left", e.clientX);
      $("#arltcntn").css("bottom", $(window).height()-e.clientY);
      $("#arltcntn").css("right", "auto");
      $("#arltcntn").css("top", "auto");
    } else if(e.clientY > windowHeight && e.clientX > windowWidth) {
      $("#arltcntn").css("right", $(window).width()-e.clientX);
      $("#arltcntn").css("bottom", $(window).height()-e.clientY);
      $("#arltcntn").css("left", "auto");
      $("#arltcntn").css("top", "auto");
    } else if(e.clientY <= windowHeight && e.clientX <= windowWidth) {
      $("#arltcntn").css("left", e.clientX);
      $("#arltcntn").css("top", e.clientY);
      $("#arltcntn").css("right", "auto");
      $("#arltcntn").css("bottom", "auto");
    } else {
      $("#arltcntn").css("right", $(window).width()-e.clientX);
      $("#arltcntn").css("top", e.clientY);
      $("#arltcntn").css("left", "auto");
      $("#arltcntn").css("bottom", "auto");
    }
    $("#arltcntn").fadeIn(50, FocusContextOut());
      doubleClicked = true;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      doubleClicked = false;
      $("#arltcntn").fadeOut(50);
    }
  });
  function FocusContextOut() {
    $(document).on("click", function () {
      doubleClicked = false; 
      $("#arltcntn").fadeOut(50);
      $(document).off("click");           
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#arltcntn {
     display: none; position: fixed; border: 1px solid #b1b0b0; width: 250px; padding: 10px 0px 10px 15px; background: #ffffff; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px #989898; border-radius: 1px; z-index: 99999;
     
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="arltcntn">hello world i am menu</div>
```

**This is not a spam post, I research in stackoverflow and try to do but it was not helpful. I belive to my question it will be helpful for like me guys.**

Comment: Did you make a reference to the javascript file in your HTML?

Comment: It works fine - if you right-click, it brings up your custom context menu.

Comment: stop removing relevant information from your question, it makes the answers useless to future readers, it also makes the question off topic.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you reference the JQuery file before the file that you are trying to load the script from.

Comment: Use the following references
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/yourfile.js"></script>

Comment: the order of the files referenced is really important. Try adding the files on top of the page in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are missed the script file to add your HTML page.

After including the jquery library you have to include your javascript file

Like,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>
```